# How to run testdisk on a partition image (not the whole disk image)

Tags: data-recovery, disk-image, testdisk

I did accidentally override the first part of a partition. Please note, the GPT partition table is completely intact. No damage done there.

That partition was as large as possible. Since I only have another same-sized disk (but not larger), I created a disk-image of the partition only.

I try to run `testdisk` on that image but all available options seem to include *rescuing a partition table*. [That answer](https://superuser.com/a/1582828/696153) on my last question seems do imply that `testdisk` can very much recover partially damaged file systems – exactly what I need.

So, how do I run tesdisk on a partition image only (I know the file system type, it's ext4) with the purpose of recovering whatever data is still there.

---

I already run foremost. The result is nice and all, but my most valuable data is a) a data.db sqlite database (that's a not-supported file type as far as I'm aware) and b) a .thunderbird folder (the folder-structure is quit important for that one)

Comment: Only a comment, since I can barely remember the details of my solution back then: But I actually was able to rescue the data!
The problem: The very first block within ext4 (which contains metadata about the filesystem) was overriden.
The solution: copies of that one are at other positions in the file system. Just copy it from there to the first block!

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if doing this would help - My understanding is that testdisks ability to recover/repair filesystem's is very limited.  Testdisk is primarily a partition recovery tool, with only marginal support for ext4 operations - ie copying deleted ext4 files.

As per https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk -

```
   primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again
```

And its ext filesystem support is only

```
  Undelete files from ext2 filesystem
```

If the partition is already in place, presumably you could read the disk and then just do file recovery with no Ill effects.  That said, I imagine extundelete would be a better tool for this job.

Depending on the type of loss, Photorec (part of the testdisk suite) may apparently  be able to identify .sqlite files.

Comment: extundelete seems to for working file systems when single files are accidentally deleted. My filesystem is corrupted, especially the first superblock is definitely gone. (As I wrote in my [previous question](https://superuser.com/q/1582700/696153) the first part of the partition is gone.)

Comment: Yes, but I see no evidence that testdisk can help you.